# How do I filter a list through a formatted web scraping for loop

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I have a list of basketball players that I want to pass through a web scraping for loop I've already set up. The list of players is a list of the 2011 NBA Draft picks. I want to loop through each player and get their college stats from their final year in college. The problem is some drafted players did not go to college and therefore do not have a url formatted in their name so every time I pass in even one player that did not play in college the whole code gets an error. I have tried including "pass" and "continue" but nothing seems to work. This is the closest I gotten so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
headers = {'User Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

players = [
   'kyrie-irving','derrick-williams','enes-kanter',
   'tristan-thompson','jonas-valanciunas','jan-vesely',
   'bismack-biyombo','brandon-knight','kemba-walker,
   'jimmer-fredette','klay-thompson'
]
#the full list of players goes on for a total of 60 players, this is just the first handful

player_stats = []

 for player in players:
    url = (f'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/{player}-1.html')
    res = requests.get(url)
    #if player in url:
        #continue
    #else:
        #print("This player has no college stats")
#Including this if else statement makes the error say header is not defined. When not included, the error says NoneType object is not iterable       
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
    header = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit = 2)[0].findAll('th')]
    rows = soup.findAll('tr')
    player_stats.append([td.getText() for td in soup.find('tr', id ='players_per_game.2011')])
    player_stats

graph = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = header)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 1 of 2 things:

1. check the response status code. 200 is successful response, anything else is an error. Problem with that is some site will have a valid html page to say "invalid page", so you could still get a successful 200 response.
2. Just use try/except. If it fails, continue to the next item in the list

Because of that issue with option 1, go with option 2 here. Also, have you considered using pandas to parse the table? It's a little easier to do (and uses BeautifulSoup under the hood)?

Lastly, you're going to need to do a little more logic with this. There are multiple college players "Derrick William". I suspect you're not meaning `https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/derrick-williams-1.html`. So you need to figure out how to work that out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
headers = {'User Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

players = [
   'kyrie-irving','derrick-williams','enes-kanter',
   'tristan-thompson','jonas-valanciunas','jan-vesely',
   'bismack-biyombo','brandon-knight','kemba-walker',
   'jimmer-fredette','klay-thompson'
]
#the full list of players goes on for a total of 60 players, this is just the first handful

player_stats = []

for player in players:
    url = (f'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/{player}-1.html')
    res = requests.get(url)

    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
        header = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit = 2)[0].findAll('th')]
        rows = soup.findAll('tr')
        player_stats.append([td.getText() for td in soup.find('tr', id ='players_per_game.2011')])
        player_stats
    except:
        print("%s has no college stats" %player)

graph = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = header)
```

With Pandas:

```
graph = pd.DataFrame()
for player in players:
    try:
        url = (f'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/{player}-1.html')
        df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
        cols = list(df.columns)
        
        df = df.iloc[-2][cols]
        df['Player'] = player
        
        graph = graph.append(df).reset_index(drop=True)
        graph = graph[['Player'] + cols]
    except:
        print("%s has no college stats" %player)
```